# SQL search through ALL fields

Tags: sql

I've got a database I'm searching through, and I want to be able to return all rows who have at least one field in them that matches the search criteria. Is there an easier way to do this than looping through all the columns? Something like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE [insert very simple code here] LIKE fieldString
```

If not I can just loop, I was just wondering if there was a simple solution I was missing.

Comment: Have you tried an monster OR statement that covers each column?

Comment: For what database?  Full Text Search (FTS) is likely the best solution

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Exactly what I was going to suggest assuming he's on SQL Server.

Comment: I agree with OMG Ponies or alternately using something like Lucene(.NET), but both of those take a little bit of set up as opposed to the long Where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ORs in your WHERE clause:

`WHERE col1 LIKE .... OR col2 LIKE .... OR col3 LIKE ...`

Comment: Okay, I was also going for that, just wondered if there was something simpler. that's simple, just makes a long statement :D nothing too bad!

Comment: Check @t-clausen.dk answer. His code does the job and is well commented

Answer (score 2):

Just put them all in an OR statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE col1 LIKE fieldString
    OR col2 LIKE fieldString
    OR col3 LIKE fieldString
```